# How to create models in GCP-BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, arima

I have a table with around 1000 time series in the columns. I need to calculate an ARIMA in GCP Big-Query for each one; how can I do it without creating an ARIMA model for each series, get a prediction for the next 3 periods and append it to the series table?.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to define additional options in the `CREATE MODEL` statement.

Here is an example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL bqml_tutorial.nyc_citibike_arima_model_group
OPTIONS
  (model_type = 'ARIMA_PLUS',
   time_series_timestamp_col = 'date',
   time_series_data_col = 'num_trips',
   time_series_id_col = 'start_station_name',
   auto_arima_max_order = 5
  ) AS
SELECT
   start_station_name,
   EXTRACT(DATE from starttime) AS date,
   COUNT(*) AS num_trips
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.new_york.citibike_trips
WHERE start_station_name LIKE '%Central Park%'
GROUP BY start_station_name, date
```

The `OPTIONS(model_type='ARIMA_PLUS', time_series_timestamp_col='date', ...)` clause indicates that you are creating a set of ARIMA-based time-series `ARIMA_PLUS` models. In addition to `time_series_timestamp_col` and `time_series_data_col`, **you must specify `time_series_id_col`, which is used to annotate different input time series.**

There is a full tutorial about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/arima-multiple-time-series-forecasting-tutorial#arima-model-group) (step 4 is your use case):